# VBA IF Value is null end script else continue

Tags: vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

New to VBA so I do apologize for any stupidity here.  I am working on custom script for software we have, it seems like everywhere has excel scripting.

Working code

```
IF StrComp(XXXX.GetField("Col_1"), RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)) <> 0 
Then xxxx.SetField "Col_1" , RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)
End If
```

What is happening is the script is running fine but if there is a Blank value in Col_1 and a Null Value in Col_2 it is updating Col_1 with ****.  I would like that if Col_2 is nothing, blank or NULL to do nothing at all end script however if there is a value there to test if Col_1 = last 4 of Col_2 if those are not equal then run the update.  Hopefully this make sense.  This was my attempt but crashed and burned.

```
If RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4) Is Nothing 
THEN Exit
IF StrComp(XXXX.GetField("Col_1"), RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)) <> 0
Then xxxx.SetField "Col_1" , RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
rightVal = RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)
If IsNull(rightVal) Or rightVal = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If StrComp(XXXX.GetField("Col_1"), rightVal) <> 0 Then
    xxxx.SetField "Col_1" , rightVal
End If
```

Nothing refers to an empty Object reference is VB, so comparing to nothing wasn't quite right. Also, you need to specify what to exit, in this case "Exit Sub", and enclose it in the If block (your If statement was left wide open).

I also temporarily store the value of `RIGHT(xxxx.GetField("Col_2"), 4)` to save on recomputing every time.

Comment: This did not work but I was able to get the code working.  Similar to your example I stored both values in temporarily and then did some logic test and included NOT IsNull(Col_2)